# AngularJS 1 Selectbox is not working in OnsenUI

Tags: angularjs, onsen-ui

I am using Angular js1 and Onsen UI

In here select input is not working in Angularjs1 how can i use this input

```
<ons-page>

    <ons-toolbar>
    <div class="center">My App</div>
    </ons-toolbar>

    <div style="text-align: center; margin-top: 30px;">

    <p>
        <select modifier="tappable">
            <option value="">Select Car Model</option>
            <option >1</option>
            <option >2</option>
        </select>
    </p>

    <p style="margin-top: 30px;">
        <ons-button ng-click="submitLogin()">Sign in</ons-button>
    </p>



    </div>

</ons-page>
```

Comment: How does it not work? What is happening and what should happen?

Comment: How are you binding to the dropdown?  I don't see any type of binding.

Answer (score 0):

You might be missing an ng-model attribute to store the value for use in ng-click. Again, its a little difficult without see your js code. But you could try:

```
<p>
    <select modifier="tappable" ng-model="CarModel">
        <option disabled selected value="">Select Car Model</option>
        <option value="1">1</option>
        <option value="2">2</option>
    </select>
</p>

<p style="margin-top: 30px;">
    <ons-button ng-click="submitLogin()">Sign in</ons-button>
</p>
```

Then you could call that in the angular code by using $scope.CarModel. Here, you would see either 1 or 2 as the value.

A more angular approach to the code above would be to bind an object to the select so you can control it from the code or a back end. 
In the AngularJs code you could define it as so:

```
$scope.DataSet = [{Display:"One",Value:1},{Display:"Two",Value:2}];
```

And on the markup:

```
<select ng-model="CarModel" ng-options="Data.Value as Data.Display for Data in DataSet"></select>
```

In this case, Angular will generate the  markup for you and assign the value to the model when you click an option.

As an aside, the disabled and selected attributes on the first option allow you to force the user to select something other than the placeholder.